# Error parsing XML, line 744, column 97: The entity "u" was referenced, but not declared

Tags: xml, blogger

[image]

This always shows a message:

> Error parsing XML, line 744, column 97: The entity "u" was referenced, but not declared

How to fix this bug? Please get me out of here.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are doing. Please include error messages directly in the question as text and not as screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

in script source replace `&` with `&amp;`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is being caused by the `&` symbol present in the script tag's `src` link. You will need to escape it by replacing it with `&amp;` to make the script tag get accepted by Blogger's XML parser -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.adnetwork.com/jp.php?c=b4e403v2x256r2w2s2b43384&amp;u;=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.adnetwork.rocks"></script>
```